# Installing hardhat and git repository get a lot of vulnerabilities. Npm audit fix and npm audit fix --force not working

Tags: solidity, hardhat, nodejs, npm

I git clone this repository:

https://github.com/jamesbachini/DEX-Arbitrage

After running `npm install` get a lot of vulnerabilities.

Run `npm audit fix` and `npm audit fix --force`, but vulnerabilities are still there.

Deleted `node_modules`and `package-lock.json`and run again `npm install` but vulnerabilities are still.

Still got no response from the creator from the repository.

Any help will be really appreciated!

Here the output:

````
127 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

# npm audit report

async  2.0.0 - 2.6.3
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution in async - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-fwr7-v2mv-hh25
No fix available
node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/async
  ganache-core  <=2.1.0-beta.7 || >=2.1.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of async
  Depends on vulnerable versions of lodash
  Depends on vulnerable versions of web3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-provider-engine
  node_modules/ganache-core
    @ethereum-waffle/provider  <=4.0.1-dev.37f589d || 4.0.2-dev.0a87072 - 4.0.2-dev.c513a49 || 4.0.3-dev.0c13fb9 - 4.0.3-dev.e7e18f6 || 4.0.5-dev.06c4b26 - 4.0.5-dev.90390a9
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @ethereum-waffle/ens
    Depends on vulnerable versions of ganache-core
    node_modules/@ethereum-waffle/provider
      @ethereum-waffle/chai  2.5.0 - 4.0.0-dev.e3fa452
      Depends on vulnerable versions of @ethereum-waffle/provider
      node_modules/@ethereum-waffle/chai
        ethereum-waffle  2.3.0-istanbul.0 - 4.0.0-dev.e3fa452
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @ethereum-waffle/chai
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @ethereum-waffle/provider
        node_modules/ethereum-waffle
          @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle  *
          Depends on vulnerable versions of ethereum-waffle
          node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle

cross-fetch  <=2.2.5 || 3.0.0 - 3.0.5
Severity: moderate
Incorrect Authorization in cross-fetch - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-7gc6-qh9x-w6h8
Depends on vulnerable versions of node-fetch
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/cross-fetch

elliptic  <6.5.4
Severity: moderate
Use of a Broken or Risky Cryptographic Algorithm - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-r9p9-mrjm-926w
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/elliptic
  @ethersproject/signing-key  <=5.0.9
  Depends on vulnerable versions of elliptic
  node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/@ethersproject/signing-key

got  <11.8.5
Severity: moderate
Got allows a redirect to a UNIX socket - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-pfrx-2q88-qq97
No fix available
node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/got
node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/swarm-js/node_modules/got
  swarm-js  0.1.1 - 0.1.17 || 0.1.35 - 0.1.40
  Depends on vulnerable versions of got
  node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/swarm-js
  web3-bzz  <=1.7.4
  Depends on vulnerable versions of got
  Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
  node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-bzz
    web3  <=1.7.4 || 2.0.0-alpha - 3.0.0-rc.4
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-bzz
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-eth
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-eth-personal
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-net
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-shh
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-utils
    node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3

json-schema  <0.4.0
Severity: critical
json-schema is vulnerable to Prototype Pollution - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-896r-f27r-55mw
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/json-schema
  jsprim  0.3.0 - 1.4.1 || 2.0.0 - 2.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of json-schema
  node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/jsprim

lodash  <=4.17.20
Severity: high
Command Injection in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-35jh-r3h4-6jhm
Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-29mw-wpgm-hmr9
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/lodash

minimist  <1.2.6
Severity: critical
Prototype Pollution in minimist - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-xvch-5gv4-984h
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/minimist

node-fetch  <=2.6.6
Severity: high
The `size` option isn't honored after following a redirect in node-fetch - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-w7rc-rwvf-8q5r
node-fetch is vulnerable to Exposure of Sensitive Information to an Unauthorized Actor - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-r683-j2x4-v87g
No fix available
node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/fetch-ponyfill/node_modules/node-fetch
node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/node-fetch
  fetch-ponyfill  1.0.0 - 6.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of node-fetch
  node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/fetch-ponyfill
    eth-json-rpc-middleware  1.1.0 - 5.0.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of fetch-ponyfill
    node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/eth-json-rpc-middleware
      eth-json-rpc-infura  <=5.0.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of eth-json-rpc-middleware
      node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/eth-json-rpc-infura
        web3-provider-engine  14.0.0 - 15.0.12
        Depends on vulnerable versions of eth-json-rpc-infura
        node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine

normalize-url  4.3.0 - 4.5.0
Severity: high
ReDoS in normalize-url - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-px4h-xg32-q955
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/normalize-url

path-parse  <1.0.7
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service in path-parse - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-hj48-42vr-x3v9
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/path-parse

simple-get  <2.8.2
Severity: high
Exposure of Sensitive Information in simple-get - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-wpg7-2c88-r8xv
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/simple-get

tar  <=4.4.17
Severity: high
Arbitrary File Creation/Overwrite on Windows via insufficient relative path sanitization - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-5955-9wpr-37jh
Arbitrary File Creation/Overwrite via insufficient symlink protection due to directory cache poisoning using symbolic links - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-qq89-hq3f-393p
Arbitrary File Creation/Overwrite via insufficient symlink protection due to directory cache poisoning using symbolic links - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-9r2w-394v-53qc
Arbitrary File Creation/Overwrite due to insufficient absolute path sanitization - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-3jfq-g458-7qm9
Arbitrary File Creation/Overwrite via insufficient symlink protection due to directory cache poisoning - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-r628-mhmh-qjhw
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/tar

underscore  1.3.2 - 1.12.0
Severity: critical
Arbitrary Code Execution in underscore - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-cf4h-3jhx-xvhq
No fix available
node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/underscore
  web3-core-helpers  <=1.3.6-rc.2 || 2.0.0-alpha - 3.0.0-rc.4
  Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
  Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-eth-iban
  Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-utils
  node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-core-helpers
    web3-core  <=1.3.5 || 2.0.0-alpha - 3.0.0-rc.4
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-helpers
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-method
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-requestmanager
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-utils
    node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-core
      web3-eth-ens  <=1.3.6-rc.2 || 2.0.0-alpha - 3.0.0-rc.4
      Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
      Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core
      Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-helpers
      Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-eth-abi
      Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-eth-contract
      Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-utils
      node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-eth-ens
        web3-eth  <=1.3.6-rc.2 || 2.0.0-alpha - 3.0.0-rc.4
        Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
        Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core
        Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-helpers
        Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-method
        Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-subscriptions
        Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-eth-abi
        Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-eth-accounts
        Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-eth-contract
        Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-eth-ens
        Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-eth-iban
        Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-eth-personal
        Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-net
        Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-utils
        node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-eth
    web3-core-method  <=1.3.6-rc.2 || 2.0.0-alpha - 3.0.0-rc.4
    Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-helpers
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-subscriptions
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-utils
    node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-core-method
      web3-net  1.2.0 - 1.3.5 || 2.0.0-alpha - 3.0.0-rc.4
      Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core
      Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-method
      Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-utils
      node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-net
        web3-eth-personal  <=1.3.5 || 2.0.0-alpha - 3.0.0-rc.4
        Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core
        Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-helpers
        Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-method
        Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-net
        Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-utils
        node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-eth-personal
        web3-shh  <=1.3.5
        Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core
        Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-method
        Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-subscriptions
        Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-net
        node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-shh
    web3-core-subscriptions  <=1.3.6-rc.2 || 2.0.0-alpha - 3.0.0-rc.4
    Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-helpers
    node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-core-subscriptions
    web3-eth-contract  <=1.3.6-rc.2 || 2.0.0-alpha - 3.0.0-rc.4
    Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-helpers
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-method
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-subscriptions
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-eth-abi
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-utils
    node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-eth-contract
    web3-providers-http  <=1.0.0 || 1.2.0 - 1.3.5 || 3.0.0-rc.0 - 3.0.0-rc.4
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-helpers
    node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-providers-http
    web3-providers-ipc  <=1.3.6-rc.2 || 3.0.0-rc.0 - 3.0.0-rc.5
    Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-helpers
    node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-providers-ipc
    web3-providers-ws  <=1.3.6-rc.2 || 3.0.0-rc.0 - 3.0.0-rc.4
    Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-helpers
    node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-providers-ws
  web3-core-requestmanager  <=1.3.5 || 3.0.0-rc.0 - 3.0.0-rc.4
  Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
  Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-helpers
  Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-providers-http
  Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-providers-ipc
  Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-providers-ws
  node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager
  web3-eth-abi  <=1.3.6-rc.2 || 2.0.0-alpha - 3.0.0-rc.4
  Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
  Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-utils
  node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-eth-abi
  web3-eth-accounts  <=1.3.5 || 2.0.0-alpha - 3.0.0-rc.4
  Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
  Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core
  Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-helpers
  Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-core-method
  Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-utils
  node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-eth-accounts
  web3-utils  1.0.0-beta.8 - 1.3.5 || 2.0.0-alpha - 3.0.0-rc.4
  Depends on vulnerable versions of underscore
  node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-utils
    web3-eth-iban  <=1.3.5 || 2.0.0-alpha - 3.0.0-rc.4
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-utils
    node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-eth-iban


ws  5.0.0 - 5.2.2
Severity: moderate
ReDoS in Sec-Websocket-Protocol header - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-6fc8-4gx4-v693
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/node_modules/ws

yargs-parser  <=5.0.0
Severity: moderate
yargs-parser Vulnerable to Prototype Pollution - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-p9pc-299p-vxgp
No fix available
node_modules/@ensdomains/ens/node_modules/yargs-parser
  yargs  4.0.0-alpha1 - 7.0.0-alpha.3 || 7.1.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs-parser
  node_modules/@ensdomains/ens/node_modules/yargs
    solc  0.3.6 - 0.4.26
    Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
    node_modules/@ensdomains/ens/node_modules/solc
      @ensdomains/ens  *
      Depends on vulnerable versions of solc
      node_modules/@ensdomains/ens
        @ethereum-waffle/ens  <=4.0.1-dev.e7e18f6 || 4.0.3-dev.06c4b26 - 4.0.3-dev.90390a9
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @ensdomains/ens
        node_modules/@ethereum-waffle/ens

51 vulnerabilities (4 low, 12 moderate, 11 high, 24 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.```
````

Comment: Consider using my [Hardhat template](https://github.com/paulrberg/hardhat-template) and Yarn instead of Npm.

Comment: I'll have a look at it. Not sure if this will help. Anyway appreciate your suggestion. One question though, Do I install this on the folder from the git repository I'm using?

Comment: you just start from scratch using my template. Follow the instructions in the README!

Comment: I appreciate a lot your time. But what I've seen it must have an INFURA_API_KEY and my MNEMONIC. In this case I'm will work on the Polygon network. So I wouldn't need that right? I'm reading the README and docs but still can't get why this would be useful for the git repository I want to clone. Any help will be super appreciated. Because I'm a newbie, a self-taught developer getting into Blockchain. Quite a lonely road....

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after upgrading all the dependencies I still got the same vulnerabilities. Even if I would get rid off the vulnerabilities I would get incompatibilities with the code, using different versions.

After reading everywhere came to the conclusion as many said. JS packages sucks :D

Learnt to live with the vulnerabilities. Not the best solution but is the only one that let's you keep learning and working.